# PHPStorm Symfony 2 without code assist

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

I got problem with code assist in PHPStorm 5.04. I tried to add Symfony vendor folder as a External Library, but it doesn't work.

How to solve the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHPStorm is having trouble autocompleting when your code has errors.**

You extend a Controller class but it is not declared in a "use" statement and that's why PHPStorm won't know which class are you extending and it can not autocomplete.

Comment: It doesn't work at all. The user class is without code assist too and it's declared.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a specific "Framework Integration" in your Settings.
Search for "Symfony2" and choose your app/console path.